# Resizing photo before save or before upload to server

Tags: android, image, camera

I have this piece of code:

```
    @Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    File pictureFileDir = getDir();
    if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs()) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Dir not created. (ERR#GRA1)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss", Locale.US);
    String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    photoFile = acao + android_id + "_" + date + "_" + coordenadas + ".jpg";
    String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + photoFile;
    File pictureFile = new File(filename);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Login.totalTiradas++;
    } catch (Exception error) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Not saved. (ERR#GRA2)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
    }

    camera2.startPreview();
    aviso.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    String stringUrl = "111.222.333.444";

    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) { 
        new conectaFTP().execute(stringUrl);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Fail. Image not sent. (ERR#CON1)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }        
}
```

It save the photo to SD card, calls an AsyncTask and uploads the picture. All works fine.

I need to resize the picture. Before saving or before uploading, anyone is good for me.

I couldnt make `inSampleSize` or `Camera.setParameters` to work properly (my bad, for sure), or if it's the better way to do this.

Comment: you can crop your image captured before saving (alternative if you wish to crop). using `inSampleSize` should work fine. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using `setParameters`:

```
Camera.Parameters parametro = camera.getParameters();
parametro.setFlashMode("on");
List<Size> sizes = parametro.getSupportedPictureSizes();
for (int i = 0; i < sizes.size(); i++) {
    largura = sizes.get(i).width;
    altura = sizes.get(i).height;
    if (largura >= maxLargura) { break; }
}
parametro.setPictureSize(largura, altura);
camera.setParameters(parametro);
```

Comment: Each device has a set of pictures resolutions. I got the suported ones (getSupportedPictureSizes) and scan it to find the one is close the one I want and break the loop. The I apply height and width to camera parameters. I dont know I'm clear enough...

Answer (score 0):

First create a `Bitmap` from `byte[]`

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
```

then scale it using `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()`

`bmp=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height, true);` // true for if bilinear filter is enabled